# Intermittent ECONNREFUSED in selenium grid 2

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, selenium-grid

I have been trying to run our cucumber tests on a large Selenium Grid, we have been experiencing an intermittent error with the message `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)` . The error seems to occur in about 5% of our tests randomly, it isn't always the same test that fails.

I am using Amazon EC2 instances to run our grid, I have 57 nodes set-up which connect to a Selenium HUB which is also running in the Amazon environment. The tests are being run on firefox 27.0.1 and each node is configured to run up to 5 firefox instances at once. The Node and HUB instances are running Windows server 2008 R2. The node instances are running the Selenium grid jar in a service so that it may interact with the desktop without a session. Windows services have access to session 0, which allows it to display a browser without anyone being logged in.

Furthermore to run the cucumber tests in parallel I am using the parallel_tests gem ( https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests ).

To simplify the set-up and tear down process of our infrastructure, I am using Bamboo to automate the process.

I am using the selenium server jar version 2.39.0 . The Selenium web driver gem I am using is version 2.38.0. I am also using the gem watir-webdriver 0.6.4 to drive our tests, along with page object 0.9.4.

Some solutions I have considered involve rerunning the failed tests, but I haven't found an easy way to rerun failed tests in parallel at this point, I have decided that the best solution is to solve the connection error.

This is the full stack trace of the error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`block in connect'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in`timeout'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in`do_start'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in`request'
>   (eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
>   ./features/step_definitions/wizard_steps.rb:149:in`/^I pick the timezone "([^"]*)/'
>   features\SendSMS1147.feature:34:in `And I pick the timezone "(UTC+11:00) Vladivostok"'

Please note that the error doesn't only occur on this step, it occurs on a wide variety of different steps at different times, when this test is run on its own, it passes.

What is the best way to get around this error?